# synaptic No protocol specified!! error

Tags: synaptic

I have a problem , i can't open synaptic >:(

```
root@dopeboy:~# synaptic
No protocol specified
** (synaptic:6940): WARNING **: Could not open X display
No protocol specified
(synaptic:6940): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :1
```

I have try to Re-install it but is not working, any idea how to fix?! VPS Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Comment: Your copy/paste looks somewhat inexact but from what we can glean, it's looking like it wants to open a display named `:1`.  You probably don't have a display named like that, or your X session is running on a different display, and you don't have privileges on `:1`.  Try with `DISPLAY=:0.0 synaptic` (assuming you are on display 0) and/or tell us more about your displays and X sessions.

Comment: `root@dopeboy:~# exit` : To leave "root" . Then you can do `$ sudo synaptic` ... which will usually work OK. ...

Comment: thank you all but problem has gone i have rebuild my vps :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even `root` does not have the privileges to open a GUI application in your personal X session.  Log out of the `root` account and start `synaptic` with your own privileges, perhaps using `gksudo`.

```
root@dopeboy# exit
you@dopeboy$ gksudo synaptic &
```

Answer (score 0):

For me I just had to export xauthority to my regular user, not root

```
export XAUTHORITY=$HOME/.Xauthority
```

Then run it with sudo

```
sudo synaptic
```